# jQuery UI dialog open callback executes only once, but I want it to execute everytime the dialog opens

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

jQuery UI dialog open callback executes only once, but I want it to execute every time the dialog opens..

```
$('<div><b><center>'+ text +'</center></b></div>').dialog({
  title: '<b>User(s) with a similar name</b>',
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: true,
  height: 'auto',
  width: 400,
  resizable: false,
  open: function(){
    $('#smartpaginate').smartpaginator({
      totalrecords: 3,
      recordsperpage: 2,
      datacontainer: 'all-tabs',
      dataelement: 'table',
      theme: 'green'
    });
  },
  buttons: {
    "Close": function(){
      $(this).dialog('close');
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

The callback function for open executes correctly and generates pagination, but after closing, every time it opens without a pagination.

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: How do you call open() dialog? `autoOpen: true` is useless as by default it is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the dialog from DOM:

```
$('<div><b><center>'+ text +'</center></b></div>').dialog({
  title: '<b>User(s) with a similar name</b>',
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: true,
  height: 'auto',
  width: 400,
  resizable: false,
  open: function(){
    $('#smartpaginate').smartpaginator({
      totalrecords: 3,
      recordsperpage: 2,
      datacontainer: 'all-tabs',
      dataelement: 'table',
      theme: 'green'
    });
  },
  buttons: {
    "Close": function(){
$(this).remove();
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```